# Reading an int from a file returns ASCII

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, ascii

I'm currently making a game but I seem to have problems reading values from a text file.  For some reason, when I read the value, it gives me the ASCII code of the value rather than the actual value itself when I wrote it to the file.  I've tried about every ASCII conversion function and string conversion function, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I use a 2D array of integers.  I use a nested for loop to write each element into the file.  I've looked at the file and the values are correct, but I don't understand why it's returning the ASCII code.  Here's the code I'm using to write and read to file:

Writing to file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level.MaxRows(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < level.MaxCols(); j++)
    {
        fileWrite.Write(level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j) + " ");
        //Console.WriteLine(level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j));
    }

    //add new line
    fileWrite.WriteLine();
}
```

And here's the code where I read the values from the file:

```
string str = "";
int iter = 0;    //used to iterate in each column of array

for (int i = 0; i < level.MaxRows(); i++)
{
    iter = 0;
    //TODO: For some reason, the file is returning ASCII code, convert to int
    //keep reading characters until a space is reached.
    str = fileRead.ReadLine();

    //take the above string and extract the values from it.
    //Place each value in the level.
    foreach (char id in str)
    {
        if (id != ' ')
        {
            //convert id to an int
            num = (int)id;
            level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
            iter++;
        }
    }
```

This is the latest version of the loop that I use to read the values. Reading other values is fine; it's just when I get to the array, things go wrong.  I guess my question is, why did the conversion to ASCII happen?  If I can figure that out, then I might be able to solve the issue.  I'm using XNA 4 to make my game.

Answer (score 4):

This is where the convertion to ascii is happening:

```
fileWrite.Write(level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j) + " ");
```

The + operator implicitly converts the integer returned by GetValueAtIndex into a string, because you are adding it to a string (really, what did you expect to happen?)

Furthermore, the ReadLine method returns a String, so I am not sure why you'd expect a numeric value to magically come back here.  If you want to write binary data, look into [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)

Comment: The problem with that answer is, I have other values that I write to the file, and I can read those fine.  It's only the array's values that's causing the confusion.  I know that it all gets converted to a string.  I have removed the concatenation and I get the same problem.

Comment: What data type does level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j) return?  I was assuming it is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is where you are converting the characters to character codes:

```
num = (int)id;
```

The `id` variable is a `char`, and casting that to `int` gives you the character code, not the numeric value.

Also, this converts a single character, not a whole number. If you for example have `"12 34 56 "` in your text file, it will get the codes for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, not 12, 34 and 56.

You would want to split the line on spaces, and parse each substring:

```
foreach (string id in str.Split(' ')) {
  if (id.Length > 0) {
    num = Int32.Parse(id);
    level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
    iter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* I've kept the old code (below) with the assumption that one record was on each line, but I've also added a different way of doing it that should work with multiple integers on a line, separated by a space.

**Multiple records on one line**

```
str = fileRead.ReadLine();

string[] values = str.Split(new Char[] {' '});

foreach (string value in values)
{
    int testNum;

    if (Int32.TryParse(str, out testnum))
    {
        // again, not sure how you're using iter here
        level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
    }
}
```

**One record per line**

```
str = fileRead.ReadLine();

int testNum;

if (Int32.TryParse(str, out testnum))
{
    // however, I'm not sure how you're using iter here; if it's related to 
    // parsing the string, you'll probably need to do something else
    level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
}
```

Please note that the above should work if you write out each integer line-by-line (i.e. how you were doing it via the WriteLine which you remarked out in your code above). If you switch back to using a WriteLine, this should work.

Comment: @King has multiple records on each line by the look of things.

Comment: @Chris Shain Agreed, though at one point they were being written line-by-line (i.e. the commented-out WriteLine). I'll make that clearer in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
foreach (char id in str)
{
    //convert id to an int
    num = (int)id;
```

A `char` **is** an ASCII code (or can be considered as such; technically it is a unicode code-point, but that is broadly comparable assuming you are writing ANSI or low-value UTF-8).

What you want is:

```
num = (int)(id - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
fileWrite.Write(level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j) + " ");
```

converts the `int` returned from `level.GetValueAtIndex(i, j)` into a string. Assuming the function returns the value 5 for a particular `i` and `j` then you write "5 " into the file.

When you then read it is being read as a string which consists of chars and you get the ASCII code of `5` when you cast it simply to an `int`. What you need is:

```
foreach (char id in str)
{
    if (id != ' ')
    {
        //convert id to an int
        num = (int)(id - '0'); // subtract the ASCII value for 0 from your current id
        level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
        iter++;
    }
}
```

However this only works if you only ever are going to have single digit integers (only 0 - 9). This might be better:

```
foreach (var cell in fileRead.ReadLine().Split(' '))
{
     num = Int.Parse(cell);
     level.ChangeTile(i, iter, num);
     iter++;
}
```

Comment: This bit of code here is promising.  I get an error when I try it, but if I can figure it out, then I think it'll work.  The debugging showed the correct value.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I changed my code a bit, but your code put me on the right track to figuring out the problem!